# R remove NA values from 3 columns only when all 3 have NA

Tags: r

I'm trying to clean up a dataset and encountering a problem, 3 colums are related so before i can continue to do some clean up, I'd like to remove the NAs ONLY when they all 3 have them.

example

```py
      A.   B.   C.    
1.-   NA.  NA.  NA. <- to be removed
2.-   NA.  NA.  10. <- not to be removed
3.-   NA.  29.  NA  <- not to be removed
4.-   NA.  NA.  NA. <  to be removed

I have tried so far with:

subset(data, data$A == NA & data$B == NA & data$C == NA)

data_new <- data[complete.cases(data$A) & (data$B) & (data$C), ]
```

but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `complete.cases` code can be with `|` condition as `complete.cases` returns TRUE for a non-NA value and FALSE for `NA`.  Thus, by using the `OR`, we are subsetting a row having at least one non-NA

```
data[complete.cases(data$A) | complete.cases(data$B) | complete.cases(data$C),]
```

Or more easily with `rowSums`

```
data[rowSums(is.na(data[, c("A", "B", "C")])) < 3,]
```

---

Or with `dplyr` with `if_all` or `if_any`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  filter(!if_all(c(A, B, C), is.na))
```

Answer (score 1):

R does not use the `==` operator on `NA`, use `is.na()` function instead. See [in R does NA == NA?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53379501/10276092)

Data

```
DF<-data.frame(ID=c(1:4),
               A=c(NA, NA, NA, NA),
               B=c(NA, NA, 29, NA),
               C=c(NA, 10, NA, NA))
```

Base solution

```
DF[!(is.na(DF$A) & is.na(DF$B) & is.na(DF$C)),]
```

> ```
>   ID  A  B  C
> 2  2 NA NA 10
> 3  3 NA 29 NA
> ```

In your original `subset()` attempt, subset does not need to repeat the data.frame when identifying the column in the filter section (eg `DF$A` vs `A`).

```
subset(DF, !(is.na(A) & is.na(B) & is.na(C)))
#or
subset(DF, !is.na(A) | !is.na(B) | !is.na(C))
```